# Trying to access HTML calculator w/ Higher Order Function and Callbacks

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have been working through the w3 challenges and I thought I could write the solution out better than they provided.

I wanted to obey DRY principles, so I created a callback for dividing and one for multiplying and made the principle function a HOF for each callback. However, for some reason It's not working, nor is it throwing an error. I've reviewed my code and so far haven't had any luck resolving it.

In a perfect world the HTML inputs would be either multiplying or dividing the code. Yet, nothing is happening.

Any ideas?

```js
var userMultiply = function() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 * num2;
}

var userDivide = function() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 / num2;
}

function userMaths(callBack) {
  let num1 = document.getElementById('firstNumber').value;
  let num2 = document.getElementById('secondNumber').value;
}
```

```html
<form>
  1st Number : <input type="text" id="firstNumber" /><br> 2nd Number: <input type="text" id="secondNumber" /><br>
  <input type="button" onClick="userMaths(userMultiply)" Value="Multiply" />
  <input type="button" onClick="userMaths(userDivide)" Value="Divide" />
  <p>The result is: </p>
  <span id="result"></span>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several problems:

1. You never call the callback.
2. The variables `num1` and `num2` are local variables in `userMaths`, they can't be accessed from `userMultiply` and `userDivide`. You should pass them as parameters.

You should also convert the inputs to numbers with `parseFloat()`. Operators like `*` and `/` do this automatically, but you'll run into a problem when you add `userAdd`, because `+` will do string concatenation instead of addition.

You might also want to move the code that displays the result into `userMaths`, since it's the same for all operations.

```js
var userMultiply = function(num1, num2) {
  return num1 * num2;
}

var userDivide = function(num1, num2) {
  return num1 / num2;
}

function userMaths(callBack) {
  let num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('firstNumber').value);
  let num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('secondNumber').value);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = callBack(num1, num2);
}
```

```html
<form>
  1st Number : <input type="text" id="firstNumber" /><br> 2nd Number: <input type="text" id="secondNumber" /><br>
  <input type="button" onClick="userMaths(userMultiply)" Value="Multiply" />
  <input type="button" onClick="userMaths(userDivide)" Value="Divide" />
  <p>The result is: </p>
  <span id="result"></span>
</form>
```